# Disable client side DNS caching on windows 7 for a domain

Tags: caching, windows-7, dns

Is there a way to disable DNS caching for a particular domain name only on windows 7. I know that I can disable the DNS caching completely by disabling "DNS Client" service, but, I just want to disable DNS caching for a single domain name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about that, but if it helps you can override it using the hosts file: \Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Answer (score 1):

[image: Create the following registry keys]

Create the registry keys, NegativeCacheTime and Max NegativeCacheTtl , these will disable negative DNS caching on client side